# How to optimize pipeline stalls due to L1D Cache Bound code in Haswell for a Matrix-Matrix multiply kernel?

Tags: c, optimization, cpu-usage, matrix-multiplication, avx2

I'm trying to optimize several kernels for AVX2 to further my understanding on micro-architectural software optimizations. One of the kernels I am writing is a tiled matrix-matrix multiply. I profiled the execution with Intel VTune and found the code is L1D Cache bound. I did some research on what this means and came across [this article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-help-l1-bound) from Intel where some possible causes are outlined. After reading the distinct possibilities, I alleviated some of the issues by adding an accumulator to prevent the longer dependency chain. I've peeked into the generated assembly, but I am not too knowledgable in assembly code.

My implementation performs at roughly 50% the MKL DGEMM performance for the same inputs. This coincides with VTune which indicates 50% performance of the memory pipeline stalls.

The code spends over 90% of the time in the following kernel:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h> //AVX2

#define MU 16
#define NU 16
#define KU 8
#define MINIMUM(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))

static inline void tiny_dgemm_ijk(const double* A, const double* B, double *restrict C, const int i, const int j, const int k, const int lda, const int ldb, const int ldc){
    __m256d cvec1, cvec2, cvec3, cvec4, cvec5, cvec6, cvec7, cvec8;
    __m256d cvec9, cvec10, cvec11, cvec12, cvec13, cvec14, cvec15, cvec16;
    __m256d avec1, avec2, avec3, avec4, avec5, avec6, avec7, avec8;
    __m256d bvec1, bvec2;
    // Iterate over a chunk of NU columns of C.
    for (int jjj = 0; (jjj < NU); jjj++){
        // Load a chunk of C of dimensions 16 by 1
        cvec1 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 0));
        cvec2 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 4));
        cvec3 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 8));
        cvec4 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 12));
        cvec5 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
        cvec6 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
        cvec7 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
        cvec8 = _mm256_set1_pd(0.0);
        // Iterate over KU columns of A and rows of B
        // Perform FMA operation over all 16 rows of A corresponding to the 16 rows of C.
        for (int kkk = 0; (kkk < KU); kkk+=2){
            bvec1 = _mm256_set1_pd(B[(kkk + k + 0) + (jjj + j)*ldb]);
            bvec2 = _mm256_set1_pd(B[(kkk + k + 1) + (jjj + j)*ldb]);

            avec1 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + (kkk+k)*lda + 0));
            avec2 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + (kkk+k)*lda + 4));
            cvec1 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec1, bvec1, cvec1);
            cvec2 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec2, bvec1, cvec2);

            avec3 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + (kkk+k)*lda + 8));
            avec4 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + (kkk+k)*lda + 12));
            cvec3 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec3, bvec1, cvec3);
            cvec4 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec4, bvec1, cvec4);

            avec5 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + ((kkk+k)+1)*lda + 0));
            avec6 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + ((kkk+k)+1)*lda + 4));
            cvec5 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec5, bvec2, cvec5);
            cvec6 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec6, bvec2, cvec6);

            avec7 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + ((kkk+k)+1)*lda + 8));
            avec8 = _mm256_loadu_pd((__m256d*) (A + i + ((kkk+k)+1)*lda + 12));
            cvec7 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec7, bvec2, cvec7);
            cvec8 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(avec8, bvec2, cvec8);
        }
        // Write back to C
        _mm256_storeu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 0), _mm256_add_pd(cvec1, cvec5));
        _mm256_storeu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 8), _mm256_add_pd(cvec3, cvec7));
        _mm256_storeu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 4), _mm256_add_pd(cvec2, cvec6));
        _mm256_storeu_pd((__m256d*) (C + i + (jjj+j)*ldc + 12), _mm256_add_pd(cvec4, cvec8));
    }
}
```

For context, the kernel is called inside the following function,

```
void square_dgemm (const int n, const double* A, const double* B, double *restrict C){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j += NU){
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k += KU){
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i += MU){
                if (((i+MU) < n) && ((j+NU) < n) && ((k+KU) < n)){
                    // Handle core of the GEMM divisible by chunks.
                    // The remainder of the branches are handled by
                    // less optimal sections. Over 90% of runtime is
                    // spent in tiny_dgemm_ijk.
                    tiny_dgemm_ijk(A, B, C, i, j, k, n, n, n);
                } else if (((i+MU) < n) && ((k+KU) < n)){
                   int J = MINIMUM((j+NU), n);
                   for (int jjj = j; (jjj < J); jjj++){
                       for (int kkk = 0; (kkk < KU/2); kkk++){
                           const double bij1 = B[kkk+k+jjj*n];
                           const double bij2 = B[kkk+k+(KU/2)+jjj*n];
                           for (int iii = 0; (iii < MU/4); iii++){
                               C[iii+i+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+0+(kkk+k)*n] * bij1;
                               C[iii+i+(MU/4)+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(MU/4)+0+(kkk+k)*n] * bij1;
                               C[iii+i+(MU/2)+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(MU/2)+0+(kkk+k)*n] * bij1;
                               C[iii+i+(3*(MU/4))+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(3*(MU/4))+0+(kkk+k)*n] * bij1;

                               C[iii+i+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+0+(kkk+k+(KU/2))*n] * bij2;
                               C[iii+i+(MU/4)+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(MU/4)+0+(kkk+k+(KU/2))*n] * bij2;
                               C[iii+i+(MU/2)+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(MU/2)+0+(kkk+k+(KU/2))*n] * bij2;
                               C[iii+i+(3*(MU/4))+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(3*(MU/4))+0+(kkk+k+(KU/2))*n] * bij2;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                } else if ((i+MU) < n) {
                   int J = MINIMUM((j+NU), n);
                   int K = MINIMUM((k+KU), n);
                   for (int jjj = j; (jjj < J); jjj++){
                       for (int kkk = k; (kkk < K); kkk++){
                           const double bij1 = B[kkk+jjj*n];
                           for (int iii = 0; (iii < MU/4); iii++){
                               C[iii+i+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+0+(kkk)*n] * bij1;
                               C[iii+i+(MU/4)+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(MU/4)+0+(kkk)*n] * bij1;
                               C[iii+i+(MU/2)+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(MU/2)+0+(kkk)*n] * bij1;
                               C[iii+i+(3*(MU/4))+0+(jjj)*n] += A[iii+i+(3*(MU/4))+0+(kkk)*n] * bij1;
                           }
                       }
                   }
                } else {
                    int J = MINIMUM((j+NU), n);
                    int K = MINIMUM((k+KU), n);
                    for (int jjj = j; (jjj < J); jjj++){
                        for (int kkk = k; (kkk < K); kkk++){
                            const double bij = B[kkk+jjj*n];
                            for (int iii = i; (iii < n); iii++){
                                C[iii+jjj*n] += A[iii+kkk*n] * bij;
                            }
                        }
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not an expert in either low-level programming or micro-arch optimizations, but I am certain the data is in L1D cache for the majority of the computation. Are there any obvious causes for high L1D latency? I am compiling using the Intel C Compiler and have tried multiple optimization flag combinations with extremely similar results.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance.

**UPDATE**

Just in case anyone would like to take a look at the assembly output by ICC, I've extracted the relevant lines (at least that I can tell).

```
        movslq    %r14d, %r14                                   #51.49
        xorb      %r9b, %r9b                                    #38.5
        movl      %esi, 1896(%rsp)                              #[spill]
        movq      264(%rsp), %rsi                               #[spill]
        movq      248(%rsp), %rcx                               #[spill]
        vmovupd   64(%rsi,%r14,8), %ymm15                       #56.49
        vmovupd   32(%rsi,%r14,8), %ymm12                       #52.49
        vmovupd   %ymm15, 704(%rsp)                             #56.49[spill]
        vmovupd   96(%rsi,%r14,8), %ymm15                       #57.49
        vmovupd   %ymm12, 1120(%rsp)                            #38.5[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm15, 672(%rsp)                             #57.49[spill]
        vmovupd   (%rcx,%r14,8), %ymm15                         #61.49
        vmovupd   %ymm15, 640(%rsp)                             #61.49[spill]
        vmovupd   32(%rcx,%r14,8), %ymm15                       #62.49
        movl      %edi, 2056(%rsp)                              #[spill]
        movq      216(%rsp), %r12                               #[spill]
        movq      224(%rsp), %r11                               #[spill]
        movq      240(%rsp), %rdi                               #[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm15, 608(%rsp)                             #62.49[spill]
        vmovupd   96(%rdi,%r14,8), %ymm13                       #67.49
        vmovupd   32(%r11,%r14,8), %ymm14                       #62.49
        vmovupd   64(%r11,%r14,8), %ymm7                        #66.49
        vmovupd   96(%r11,%r14,8), %ymm8                        #67.49
        vmovupd   (%r12,%r14,8), %ymm9                          #51.49
        vmovupd   96(%r12,%r14,8), %ymm10                       #57.49
        vmovupd   64(%rcx,%r14,8), %ymm15                       #66.49
        vmovupd   (%rdi,%r14,8), %ymm2                          #61.49
        vmovupd   32(%rdi,%r14,8), %ymm3                        #62.49
        vmovupd   64(%rdi,%r14,8), %ymm4                        #66.49
        vmovupd   %ymm13, 544(%rsp)                             #67.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm14, 736(%rsp)                             #62.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm7, 768(%rsp)                              #66.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm8, 800(%rsp)                              #67.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm9, 832(%rsp)                              #51.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm10, 864(%rsp)                             #57.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm15, 576(%rsp)                             #66.49[spill]
        vmovupd   32(%r12,%r14,8), %ymm14                       #52.49
        vmovupd   64(%r12,%r14,8), %ymm13                       #56.49
        vmovupd   (%rsi,%r14,8), %ymm7                          #51.49
        vmovupd   %ymm2, 448(%rsp)                              #61.49[spill]
        vmovupd   96(%rcx,%r14,8), %ymm15                       #67.49
        vmovupd   %ymm3, 480(%rsp)                              #62.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm4, 512(%rsp)                              #66.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm7, 1088(%rsp)                             #38.5[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm13, 928(%rsp)                             #38.5[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm15, 352(%rsp)                             #67.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm14, 896(%rsp)                             #38.5[spill]
        movl      %ebx, 344(%rsp)                               #[spill]
        movq      256(%rsp), %rbx                               #[spill]
        movq      208(%rsp), %r13                               #[spill]
        vmovupd   64(%rbx,%r14,8), %ymm0                        #56.49
        vmovupd   96(%rbx,%r14,8), %ymm1                        #57.49
        vmovupd   (%r13,%r14,8), %ymm11                         #61.49
        vmovupd   32(%r13,%r14,8), %ymm10                       #62.49
        vmovupd   64(%r13,%r14,8), %ymm9                        #66.49
        vmovupd   96(%r13,%r14,8), %ymm8                        #67.49
        vmovupd   (%rbx,%r14,8), %ymm6                          #51.49
        vmovupd   32(%rbx,%r14,8), %ymm5                        #52.49
        vmovupd   %ymm0, 384(%rsp)                              #56.49[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm1, 416(%rsp)                              #57.49[spill]
        vmovupd   (%r11,%r14,8), %ymm0                          #61.49
        vmovupd   %ymm8, 1056(%rsp)                             #38.5[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm9, 1024(%rsp)                             #38.5[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm10, 992(%rsp)                             #38.5[spill]
        vmovupd   %ymm11, 960(%rsp)                             #38.5[spill]
        movq      232(%rsp), %r15                               #[spill]
        movq      1976(%rsp), %r8                               #[spill]
        movl      %edx, 1888(%rsp)                              #[spill]
        movl      %r10d, 1200(%rsp)                             #[spill]
        lea       (%r8,%r14,8), %r10                            #39.45
        movl      %eax, 1208(%rsp)                              #[spill]
        xorl      %eax, %eax                                    #38.5
        movl      272(%rsp), %edx                               #[spill]
        movl      344(%rsp), %ebx                               #38.5[spill]
        movl      1896(%rsp), %esi                              #38.5[spill]
        movl      1936(%rsp), %r12d                             #38.5[spill]
        movl      2024(%rsp), %r8d                              #38.5[spill]
        movl      1904(%rsp), %ecx                              #38.5[spill]
        movl      2056(%rsp), %edi                              #38.5[spill]
        movq      1968(%rsp), %r13                              #38.5[spill]
        vmovupd   (%r15,%r14,8), %ymm4                          #51.49
        vmovupd   32(%r15,%r14,8), %ymm3                        #52.49
        vmovupd   64(%r15,%r14,8), %ymm2                        #56.49
        vmovupd   96(%r15,%r14,8), %ymm1                        #57.49
                                # LOE r10 r13 eax edx ecx ebx esi edi r8d r12d r14d r9b ymm0 ymm1 ymm2 ymm3 ymm4 ymm5 ymm6
L_B1.15:                        # Preds L_B1.15 L_B1.14
                                # Execution count [1.10e+02]
        vmovupd   416(%rsp), %ymm8                              #59.21[spill]
        lea       (%r12,%rax), %r11d                            #39.61
        movslq    %r11d, %r11                                   #39.61
        lea       (%rdx,%rax), %r15d                            #48.64
        movslq    %r15d, %r15                                   #48.64
        incb      %r9b                                          #38.5
        addl      %edi, %eax                                    #38.5
        vmovupd   64(%r10,%r11,8), %ymm12                       #45.45
        vmovupd   (%r10,%r11,8), %ymm14                         #39.45
        vmovupd   32(%r10,%r11,8), %ymm13                       #44.45
        vbroadcastsd (%r13,%r15,8), %ymm15                      #48.21
        vbroadcastsd 8(%r13,%r15,8), %ymm7                      #49.21
        vfmadd231pd 384(%rsp), %ymm15, %ymm12                   #58.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd %ymm15, %ymm6, %ymm14                       #53.21
        vfmadd231pd %ymm15, %ymm5, %ymm13                       #54.21
        vfmadd213pd 96(%r10,%r11,8), %ymm8, %ymm15              #59.21
        vmulpd    448(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm9                       #63.21[spill]
        vmulpd    480(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm10                      #64.21[spill]
        vmulpd    512(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm11                      #68.21[spill]
        vmulpd    544(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm8                       #69.21[spill]
        vbroadcastsd 16(%r13,%r15,8), %ymm7                     #48.21
        vfmadd231pd %ymm4, %ymm7, %ymm14                        #53.21
        vfmadd231pd %ymm3, %ymm7, %ymm13                        #54.21
        vfmadd231pd %ymm2, %ymm7, %ymm12                        #58.21
        vfmadd231pd %ymm1, %ymm7, %ymm15                        #59.21
        vbroadcastsd 24(%r13,%r15,8), %ymm7                     #49.21
        vfmadd231pd 736(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm10                    #64.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 768(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm11                    #68.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 800(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm8                     #69.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd %ymm0, %ymm7, %ymm9                         #63.21
        vbroadcastsd 32(%r13,%r15,8), %ymm7                     #48.21
        vfmadd231pd 832(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm14                    #53.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 896(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm13                    #54.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 928(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm12                    #58.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 864(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm15                    #59.21[spill]
        vbroadcastsd 40(%r13,%r15,8), %ymm7                     #49.21
        vfmadd231pd 960(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm9                     #63.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 992(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm10                    #64.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 1024(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm11                   #68.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 1056(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm8                    #69.21[spill]
        vbroadcastsd 48(%r13,%r15,8), %ymm7                     #48.21
        vfmadd231pd 1088(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm14                   #53.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 1120(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm13                   #54.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 704(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm12                    #58.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 672(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm15                    #59.21[spill]
        vbroadcastsd 56(%r13,%r15,8), %ymm7                     #49.21
        vfmadd231pd 640(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm9                     #63.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 608(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm10                    #64.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 576(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm11                    #68.21[spill]
        vfmadd231pd 352(%rsp), %ymm7, %ymm8                     #69.21[spill]
        vaddpd    %ymm9, %ymm14, %ymm9                          #72.64
        vaddpd    %ymm10, %ymm13, %ymm10                        #74.64
        vaddpd    %ymm11, %ymm12, %ymm11                        #73.64
        vaddpd    %ymm8, %ymm15, %ymm12                         #75.65
        vmovupd   %ymm9, (%r10,%r11,8)                          #72.38
        vmovupd   %ymm10, 32(%r10,%r11,8)                       #74.38
        vmovupd   %ymm11, 64(%r10,%r11,8)                       #73.38
        vmovupd   %ymm12, 96(%r10,%r11,8)                       #75.38
        cmpb      $16, %r9b                                     #38.5
        jb        L_B1.15       # Prob 93%                      #38.5
```

Comment: `movslq` (aka MOVSXD) shows that your compiler is failing to optimize away sign-extension from `int` pointer width.  You could save some front-end bandwidth if you use `size_t` or `ptrdiff_t` for you loop counters.  Also IDK why ICC would ever use `xorb` to zero a register.  That's just an obvious missed optimization vs. `xorl %r9d, %rd9`, creating a false dependency on the old value of the register.

Comment: It's also probably not great that there are so many indexed addressing modes that can't micro-fuse with `vfmadd231pd`, or use the port 7 AGU for stores.  ([Micro fusion and addressing modes](//stackoverflow.com/q/26046634)).  That might be part of why it bottlenecks on load/store port throughput (if that's what VTune means when it says L1d cache bound.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. You were right about the extra pressure on the frontend due to movslq. Making the loop indexes unsigned added an extra 1-2% to the overall peak performance. The compiler is now optimizing the `xorb` to `xorl` on inner loop counters. I am not extremely proficient on micro-op fusion or how to influence it at a higher level. Is there something I could do to alleviate pressure on Port 1 and allow for higher Port 7 usage? Once again, thanks for the excellent suggestions.

Comment: Using pointer increments in the source *might* convince the compiler to do it that way and allow more port 7 for stores.  Re: port 1: On Haswell FP addition can only run on port 1.  (But FMA can run on p0 or p1, so if p1 was becoming a real throughput bottleneck, the issue/rename/allocate stage should be sending more FMAs to port 0.)  Skylake runs add/mul/fma identically, on the FMA units on p0/p1.

Comment: Once again, thanks for the insight. I managed to get another couple percentages by changing the register allocation policy to one region per loop. Aside from that, I do believe I am saturating the available FMA units. I have not tested the code on Skylake, but I will try to see if the performance improves do to the more balanced distribution. Thanks! (PD I am leaving [this link](https://blogs.fau.de/hager/archives/8683) for anyone interested  on the limitations of the Port 7 AGU on Haswell, and the associated difficulty in reaching peak performance.)

Comment: that link points out the unfortunate limitation of the port 7 AGU to only run "simple" addressing modes, but doesn't mention unlamination: the other downside of indexed addressing modes that can lead to front-end bottlenecks.  (Probably because it wasn't well documented or known, and the updated rules for Haswell weren't even in Intel's optimization manual until after I posted about them on Stack Overflow, and in a gcc or clang bug.  IDK if there was any causality there :P)  And yes, indexing loads relative to stores or vice versa can help to reduce loop overhead.

Comment: BTW, IceLake (Sunny Cove) may have fixed this.  It has 2x load AGUs, 2x store AGUs (and 2x store-data ports), no longer making stores ever share with loads if I'm understanding it correctly.  https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/sunny_cove#Block_diagram. So I assume the store ports must be able to handle complex stores.  Un-lamination or not for AVX instructions with indexed addressing modes is still unknown, unless the optimization manual says anything about it.